# Asymptotic Notation

Tags: algorithm, math, asymptotic-complexity

This is a problem on **Asymptotic Notation** from the assignment of MIT OpenCourse *Introduction to Algorithm*:
For each of the following statements, decide whether it is **always true**, **never true**, or **sometimes true** for asymptotically nonnegative functions *f* and *g*. If it is **always true** or **never true**, explain why. If it is **sometimes true**, give one example for which it is true, and one for which it is false.

```
f(n) ≠ O(g(n)) and g(n) ≠ O(f(n))   (both are Big-O notes)
```

I think it is **never true**. Here's my proof:

```
   f(n) ≠ O(g(n))
=> f(n) = w(g(n))   (little-omega note)
=> g(n) = o(f(n))   (little-o note)
=> g(n) = O(f(n))   (big-O note)
```

the result contradicts to `g(n) ≠ O(f(n)) (Big-O note)`. Likewise,

```
   g(n) ≠ O(f(n))
=> g(n) = w(f(n))   (little-omega note)
=> f(n) = o(g(n))   (little-o note)
=> f(n) = O(g(n))   (big-O note)
```

which contradicts to `f(n) ≠ O(g(n)) (Big-O note)`.

The solution says it is **sometimes true**:

```
For f(n) = 1 and g(n) = ||n*sin(n)|| it is true,  
while for any f(n) = O(g(n)), e.g. f(n) = g(n) = 1, it is not true.
```

Where have I done wrong in my proof? Also, I cannot understand the solution. `||n*sin(n)||` looks like **vector norm** to me.

Comment: Assuming ||n sin(n)|| should read |n sin(n)| and refer to the absolute value of a real (of course, this is a vector norm on R^1), the counterexample makes sense. The could have chosen n*(1+(-1)^n) = 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, ... instead.

Comment: A didactical sidenote: maybe you want f=O(g) be a partial ordering on the set of functions, since it feels so similar to f≤g for real numbers f, g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is not true : from this `f(n) ≠ O(g(n))` it does not follow this: `f(n) = w(g(n))`. The two functions might intersect at some point and then slap places, the other becoming bigger (if I use simple words).

The function they chose is just this case: for n <= 1 the first f(n) > g(n) and there exist ns for which g(n) > f(n) (e.g pi / 2).

Answer (score 3):

I think `n*sin(n)` just shows that it is a function which keeps getting larger & smaller than `f(n) = 1` for subsequent values of n even for all choices of a *constant multiplier* used for defining Big O & thus `f(n) ≠ O(g(n)) and g(n) ≠ O(f(n))`

A Naively chosen function like `g(n) = 2*sin(n)` won't do good here. One might think that this would also keep alternating around `f(n) = 1` , but `g(n) = O(f(n)) : M*f(n) > g(n) for M = 3` etc

Comment: yeah, exactly, functions like `n*sin(n)` are just so beautiful